# Zip Stream in PHP

Tags: php, zip, stream

I have a PHP script that creates a zip file on the fly and forces the browser to download the zip file. The question is: could I directly write the zip file to an output stream which is connected to the user's browser rather than save it as a real file on the server first and then send the file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer to this question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4357904/416630

Answer (score 16):

If your web server is running Linux, then you *can* do it streaming without a temp file being generated. Under Win32, you may need to use Cygwin or something similar.

If you use `-` as the zip file name, it will compress to STDOUT. That can be redirected straight to the requester using `passthru()`. The `-q` argument simply tells `zip` to not output the status text it normally would. See the **zip(1)** manpage for more info.

```php
$zipfilename = 'zip_file_name.zip';

$files = array();

$target = '/some/directory/of/files/you/want/to/zip';

$d = dir( $target );

while( false !== ( $entry = $d->read() ) )
{
    if( substr( $entry, 0, 1 ) != '.' && !is_dir( $entry ) ) 
    {
        $files[] = $entry;
    }
}

if( ! $files )
{
    exit( 'No files to zip.' );
}

header( 'Content-Type: application/x-zip' );
header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$zipfilename\"" );

$filespec = '';

foreach( $files as $entry )
{
    $filespec .= ' ' . escapeshellarg( $entry );
}

chdir( $target );

passthru( "zip -q -$filespec" );
```

Answer (score 14):

This library seems to be what you're looking for: 
https://github.com/maennchen/ZipStream-PHP

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the [zip extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php), the answer seems to be "no."  The [close method in the ZipArchive class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-close.php) is what triggers a write, and it seems to want to write to a file.  You *might* have some luck using [Streams](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php) to simulate a file, but then you're keeping the entire thing in memory, and you still couldn't send it until you're done adding files.

If you're having problems with timeouts or other problems while having a user wait for the zip file to be created, try a multi-step download process:

1. User picks whatever they pick to create the zip
2. They're taken to a status page that uses ajax calls to actually build the zip file in the background.  A pretty, distracting animation should keep their attention.
3. After the background processes build the zip, the user is redirected to a script that performs the download / redirected to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can directly stream the zip to the client using this git rep: [Zip Stream Large Files](https://github.com/ArturGrigio/php-Zip-Download-of-Large-Files-using-Buffer)

Answer (score -2):

No, you have to use a temporary file, as in [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-open.php#84646).