# Extracting the content of a downloaded zipfile without storing it to the disc in PHP

Tags: php, soap, stream, zip

I'm retrieving a zip-Archive via a SOAP call in PHP. Is there a way to extract the content without writing it to a file first? 
So far all I found seemed to rely on storing the data in a local file, extract the content and delete the file again which seems superfluous to me.

Comment: if it is not compressed, then it should be possible. but if it is compressed, then you have to decompress it to a file

Comment: Perhaps you can use the `zip://` stream. Not exactly sure how it works, as I've never used it, but you can probably find out for yourself.

Comment: @nick Unless I'm wrong, the `zip://` wrapper is only useful to open an entry from a ZIP file transparently from ZIP-unaware functions like `fopen()` and it definitively requires a file.

Comment: Please see this question as well: [Zip Stream in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078266/zip-stream-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

There are PHP classes that use gzuncompress functions for zip decompression. I think they can take zip file inside a string and if not you can adapt the code to your purposes.

This is an [example of one such class](http://pastebin.com/GWQcW9rP) (code from [here](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/19011.html) under LGPL, requires registration).

Comment: the direct way? or do they use files in one step?

Comment: Tested this class, it does not work with a zip I've created. Additionally you need to modify it to deal with streams more properly.

Comment: Too bad. Nevertheless I'd be looking around for something like that. I once used similar class with good results on server where zip php extension was not available.

Comment: There is a partial solution on http://php.net/manual/en/ref.zip.php in the comment by wdtemp at seznam dot cz (the topmost one). If there is nothing out-of-the-box available one could extend that to a full fledged extractor... I think I will stick to saving the stuff to a file which I delete seconds after that... meh.