# how to make zip file downloadable with headers php without saving it on the server

Tags: php, zip

I have this code

```
<?php
$files = array('includes/s.xlsx', 'includes/test.html');
$zipname = 'file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
  $zip->addFile($file);
 }
$zip->close();


header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=filename.zip');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
```

But  i don't want to make the zip file saved to the server i just want it to be served to the users.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ZIP is not a streamable format (the target needs to support seeking, i.e. a ZIP file cannot be simply written to a target where the previously-written data cannot be re-read and modified) what you are trying to do can't work. So the best solution (if your zip files won't be huge) is creating it in a temporary location, `readfile()` it and then delete the temporary file.

See the following Stack Overflow questions for further reference. They contain some workarounds that might be fine for you:

- [Zip Stream in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078266/zip-stream-in-php)
- [LAMP: How to create .Zip of large files for the user on the fly, without disk/CPU thrashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357073/on-the-fly-zipping-streaming-of-large-files-in-php-or-otherwise/4357904#4357904)

Answer (score 5):

Try adding this after `readfile($zipname);` :

```
// delete the file from the server
unlink($zipname);
exit;
```

Comment: And this answer is still ok in 2017.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the object `$zip` to open and modify the zip file, but `filesize()` and `readfile()` only work on file names, so you should have this:

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
```

Btw, you can use `tempnam()` to generate a "temporary" file that will be used to hold the zip contents; once `readfile()` is done you still have to `unlink()` it though.